# Rails 5: Query for record (event_type) that is not preceded by another record (event_type)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

My setup looks like this:

```
model Order
 + has_many events

model Event
 + belongs_to :order
 - type (basic attribute; no relation)
```

I have some event types that effectively "undo" other events. Like: `complete` and `uncomplete`. I'd like to form a query that asks the following:

"Looking at only `complete` and `uncomplete` event types, is the most recent event type `complete`?"

I've come up with this:

```
order.events.where(type: [:complete, :uncomplete]).order(created_at: :desc).first.complete?
```

but I'm not sure if there's a more efficient way of doing this.

*Another (bonus) challenge with this*

There's another model that holds several orders:

```
model RelatedOrder
 + has_many :orders
```

I'd also like to do the same query as above, but by evaluating every order in the group as `complete` or not.

I could use `includes` and include `Order` and `Event`, but then I'm guessing I should define a scope on each `Order`? I'm sure there's a better way than:

```
# model/related_orders.rb
def all_completed?
  related_order.completed_orders.count == related_orders.orders.count
end
```

I'm using Postgres 9.5.20.

Comment: The query you have constructed is correct but needs a little change. You should order by desc in order to get most recent.

    order.events.where(type: ["complete", "uncomplete"]).order(created_at: :desc).first.complete?

Comment: Thanks, I missed this. Updated the question to reflect this :)

Comment: Heads up - `type` is the default inheritance column in Rails and is used to derive the model class for rows when loading an assocation and using it for another purpose can have really bad side effects. Either set `self.inheritance_column = "some_other_column"` or rename the column. Its also `incomplete` and not `uncomplete`. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html